# Incorrect labels in confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have tried to create a confusion matrix on a knn-classifier in python, but the labeled classes are wrong.

The classes attribute of the dataset is 2 (for benign) and 4 (for malignant), but when I plot the confusion matrix, all labels are 2. The code I use is:

*Data source*: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29

KNN classifier on Breast Cancer Wisconsin (Diagnostic) Data Set from UCI:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data')
data.replace('?', 0, inplace=True)
data.drop('id', 1, inplace = True)


X = np.array(data.drop(' class ', 1))
Y = np.array(data[' class '])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

Plot confusion matrix

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

disp = plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, Y_test,
                               display_labels=Y,
                               cmap=plt.cm.Blues,)
```

[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flUCj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying the `display_labels` argument with `Y`, where it should just be the *target names used for plotting*. Now it's just using the two first values that appear in `Y`, which happen to be `2, 2`. Note too that, as mentioned in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html), the displayed labels will be the same as specified in `labels` if it is provided, so you just need:

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, Y_test,
                               labels=np.unique(y),
                               cmap=plt.cm.Blues,ax=ax)
```

[image]